# Is DNS-over-HTTPS(DOH) depended on at least one regular DNS query via UDP port 53 to function?

Tags: networking, dns, doh

### Context

Operating systems (Windows, MacOS, Linux, iOS, Android), but also browsers (Firefox, Brave, Edge, etc.) have ways to use DOH.

DNS-over-HTTPS works by the system talking to an endpoint like 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query'.

Let's say the client is in a network that **restricts DNS traffic over port 53 udp**. Also the router does not serve as a DNS-resolver for the client. (The network enforces using DOH (or DOT).)

### Catch22?

**How will the client resolve the first hostname 'cloudflare-dns.com' to set-up the DOH-DNS-querying connection?**

It seems that out of the box, DOH communication always requires at least one DNS query over UDP port 53. That is if you use the traditional hostname-based endpoints.

Or is this statement incorrect, are DOH provider endpoint IPs pre-loaded in Windows 11? I can see their *hostname* is preloaded, but does it actually know where to connect to if it cannot query this hostname itself before DOH?

For Cloudflare I could remember its IP-based endpoint 'https://1.1.1.1/dns-query' and perhaps for Quad9 as well, but for NextDNS and other providers the IPs are not always so easy to remember and I would need internet to lookup their IPs to make those providers work.

### Questions

Q1:
**Is DNS-over-HTTPS(DOH) depended on at least one regular DNS query via UDP port 53 to function?** To be able to resolve the DOH server's hostname itself to connect to it?

Q2: If so, in restricted networks with no port 53 fallback or other local DNS-resolver, is using IP-included DOH-endpoint-address(es) (like https://1.1.1.1/dns-query) always required for connectivity to work all the time to avoid the catch22?
(Like with hostname-included form (https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query)?)

Q3:
HTTPS relies on PKI infrastructure and certificates that have a common name (or SAN) like 'cloudflare-dns.com'. Am I breaking a validation step in the chain by using IP-included endpoints instead of hostname-included endpoints?

Q4:
This table could be a follow-up question if operating systems have different behaviours.

| Client | Sensitive to DOH-Catch22 | Comment (why not?) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MacOS (cloudflared) | ? |  |
| Windows native | ? |  |
| Firefox on MacOS | ? |  |
| Edge on MacOS | ? |  |
| Firefox on Windows | ? |  |
| Edge on Windows | ? |  |
| iOS mobileconfig | ? |  |
| Android native | ? |  |
| Linux-based via Cloudflared | ? |  |
| Linux-based via Stubby | ? |  |

Comment: What do you mean in this section: *"For Cloudflare/Quad9/NextDNS I could memorize the re-write the endpoint"*? Generally, you would only care about a single DoH provider/endpoint

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, thank you. I clarified the part a bit, but you seemed to get the gist of it. It was all about being in a catch 22 situation. Generally I agree that one endpoint is enough, it was about circumstances requiring something else than easy-IP Cloudflare or Quad9 for whatever reason in restricted networks and now I know that it requires an hostname-to-ip lookup out-of-band or a planned approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** *Is DNS-over-HTTPS(DOH) dependent on at least one regular DNS query via UDP port 53 to function?*

This is true for hostname-based endpoints, but not when using an IP-based endpoint like cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 (or a local resolver like a hosts file).

---

**Q2:** *in restricted networks with no port 53 fallback or other local DNS-resolver, is using IP-included DOH-endpoint-address(es) always required for connectivity?*

Yes, the client needs to resolve an endpoint name like `one.one.one.one` to an IP somehow. It can be cached or hard-coded in the DoH client, but unusual.

---

**Q3:** *Am I breaking a validation step in the chain by using IP-included endpoints instead of hostname-included endpoints?*

Not necessarily. Certificates can use an IP address as a valid SAN - see the Cloudflare certificate at https://1.1.1.1/ for example. However, if the DoH client also does CRL/OCSP checking, then that info should be distributed to IP-based hosts as well (Cloudflare does not). If that's not allowed, this can cause a [deadlock](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8484/).

---

**Q4:** The general behavior is the same for any DoH service. Take a look through some default providers in different applications here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS

Comment: In addition to A3, the connection endpoint doesn't necessarily have to be the same as the name to validate against – e.g. systemd-resolved supports manually specifying a domain name for SAN validation together with an IP-based endpoint. (And as for OCSP, I would really expect the service to have OCSP stapling enabled...)